# Por que não consigo modificar a string desta forma?

Tags: c, string, ponteiro, operadores, declaração-de-variável

Quando temos uma variavel int declarada, e logo depois um ponteiro para essa variavél:

```
int x = 10;
int *p = &x;
```

Para modificarmos a variável x através do ponteiro, temos de fazer:

```
*p = 20;
```

Porém, quando declaro:

```
char *string = "ABCD";
```

E tento modificá-la da mesma forma do int:

```
*string = "EFGH";
```

É apresentado um erro na hora da compilação.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Porque está tentando jogar um ponteiro como valor da variável. O literal *string*  determinado pelas aspas grava estes caracteres na memória e gera um ponteiro que pode ser jogado em uma variável. Note que o próprio ponteiro é que deve ser atribuído para a variável diretamente. O que foi usado é para colocar o ponteiro como o valor da apontado pela variável. Leia aquela linha como "no apontamento de string atribua o ponteiro de EFGH". Então basta tirar o operador de apontamento:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char *string = "ABCD";
    string = "EFGH";
    printf("%s", string);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Nb9aml). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/nduopude-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/String/ChangeObject.c).

Na declaração da variável o asterisco não é um operador, ele faz parte da declaração, então `char *` significa que o tipo da variável será "ponteiro para char".