# Uso de char e aspas em C

Tags: c, string, sintaxe, char

O que significa esse `char*` e essas aspas vazias ""?:

```
char *directionX = "";
char *directionY = "";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *` é um tipo de dado, podemos lê-lo como **ponteiro para `char`**, então significa que a variável `directionX` terá o valor de um ponteiro, ou seja, um endereço de memória que servirá de apontamento para algum dado, e no caso esse dado deve ser obrigatoriamente um caractere, ou pelo menos será será interpretado dessa maneira quando acessá-lo por essa variável.

Não quer dizer que precisa ser só um caractere, pode ser vários. Um ponteiro pode receber aritmética e continuar em endereços subsequentes e funcionar como um *array* (um vetor). Quando temos um *array* de caracteres chamamos de *string*, ou cadeia de caracteres.

A forma de expressar uma *string* no código C é pelo seu literal. Como um texto em um jornal ou outra material com conteúdo, quando o texto é uma citação você coloca entre aspas, então o literal da *string* é entre aspas. Se as aspas forem vazias você tem um texto vazio.

Neste caso está colocando um texto vazio na área estática do seu código e este texto [terminará com um nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101) (esse terminador é que ajuda determinar quando a *string* acabou e ponteiro não deveria avançar mais), e o endereço que onde isso está será guardado em `directionX` (o mesmo vale para a outra variável). No momento de acessar você poderá pegar o endereço ou poderá pegar o apontador e ir direto no dado, ou seja na área estática onde está o texto, que neste caso só tem o terminador e mais nada, então não tem muita serventia.

Este código é pouco útil porque você não pode alterar o valor da área estática, mas pode apontar a variável para outro local onde tenha um texto mais significativo. Você poderia fazer depois:

```
directionX = "algo util aqui";
```

ou

```
directionX = directionX;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/TypeDeclaration.c).

ainda que neste exemplo dê na mesma. Mas neste caso as duas variáveis apontariam para o mesmo objeto, o que é diferente de duas variáveis apontarem para objetos diferentes que por acaso tem o mesmo valor.

Cuidado com o uso indiscriminado de ponteiro, é muito fácil corromper a memória. Programadores experientes vivem fazendo isso mesmo entendendo todas as implicações do que fazem, imagina sem entender tudo.

Veja mais sobre *string*  em C em:

- [Qual a forma correta de se declarar um string em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/236175/101)
- [Por que não consigo modificar a string desta forma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/102649/101)
- [Dúvida em relação a ponteiros em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/155557/101)
- [Qual o motivo de algumas funções que trabalham com strings em C iniciarem com *?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/201287/101)

Principalmente siga os *links* dentro dessas perguntas, tem informação bastante relevante. E aconselho pegar um livro, aprender de forma aleatória não costuma dar muito certo.

Muito complicado? Talvez porque está pulando algumas etapas. Vai passo a passo.

Answer (score 0):

```
char directionX
```

Permite apenas um caracter, como por exemplo 'c', 'a'...etc

```
char *directionX
```

É basicamente um apontador para char que não tem memoria estática.

```
 char directionX[20]
```

É igual ao exemplo anterior, porem apenas permite 20 caracteres na string

Ao colocar "" estamos a colocar o \0 no inicio, ou seja, fica uma string vazia