# Retornar string formata de outro struct

Tags: c, char

Eu queria retornar a string formatada, que é criada na função des_Desconto, para formatar outra string da funcao itm_showItem mais não retorna nada.

`Struct item`

```
struct item{
  int ID;
  int qntd;
  float valor;
  char* descricao;
  Desconto* desconto;
};
```

`Funcao da Struc item`

```
char* itm_showItem(Item* i){
  char* saida;
  sprintf(saida, "ID: %d\nQuantidade: %d\nValor: %.2f\nDescricao: %s\nDesconto: %s\n",  
  i->ID,
  i->qntd,
  i->valor,
  i->descricao,
  des_showDesconto(i->desconto));
  return saida;
}
```

`Struct desconto`

```
struct desconto{
  int qntd;
  float valorDesconto;
};
```

`Funcao da Struct desconto`

```
char* des_showDesconto(Desconto* d){
  char* saida;
  sprintf(saida, "%.2f%% / %d item(ns)", des_getValor(d), des_getQntd(d));
  return saida;
}
```

Comment: Se declarar tua var `saida` como `static char saida[TAM_FIXO]` e fizer o retorno como `return &saida`, não da certo?

Comment: Se pensar tua var `saida` não tem nada, ta apenas apontando pra lugar nenhum. Acho que vale uma olhada nessa pergunta sobre string em c: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/321313/duvida-sobre-char-em-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse ponteiro ai não tá com memória alocada pra ele... Minha sugestão é criar uma variável temporária de um tamanho um pouco maior e depois alocar espaço baseado no tamanho final dessa string, lembrando de alocar 1 espaço a mais para o '\0'.

```
char* des_showDesconto(Desconto* d){
    char* saida;
    char temp[500]; // tou usando 500 para o tamanho maximo da string, imaginando que nunca vá existir algo que chegue a esse valor.
    sprintf(temp, "%.2f%% / %d item(ns)", des_getValor(d), des_getQntd(d));
    saida = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp) + 1));
    strcpy(saida, temp);
    return saida;
}
```

O mesmo raciocínio serve pra outra função...

Tenta organizar melhor nas próximas perguntas pra que as pessoas possam executar teu código... do jeito que tá ai não compila: essas funções getValor e getQntd por exemplo, a definição não está no código mas como o nome foi sugestivo o suficiente, eu consegui gerar um código que roda. Vou colar abaixo:

```
typedef struct Desconto{
   int qntd;
   float valorDesconto;
} Desconto;

typedef struct item{
   int ID;
   int qntd;
   float valor;
   char* descricao;
   Desconto* desconto;
 } item;

char* des_showDesconto(Desconto* d){
   char* saida;
   char temp[500]; // tou usando 500 para o tamanho maximo da string, imaginando que nunca vá existir algo que chegue a esse valor.
   sprintf(temp, "%.2f%% / %d item(ns)", d->valorDesconto, d->qntd);
   saida = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp) + 1));
   strcpy(saida, temp);
   return saida; 
}


char* itm_showItem(item* i){
   char* saida;
   char temp[500];
   sprintf(temp, "ID: %d\nQuantidade: %d\nValor: %.2f\nDescricao: %s\nDesconto: %s\n",  
   i->ID,
   i->qntd,
   i->valor,
   i->descricao,
   des_showDesconto(i->desconto));
   saida = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(temp) + 1));
   strcpy(saida, temp);
   return saida;
}

int main() 
{
    item i1;
    Desconto d;
    i1.ID = 10; i1.qntd = 2;
    i1.valor = 4.5;
    i1.descricao = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 10);
    strcpy(i1.descricao, "aew papai");
    i1.desconto = &d;
    d.qntd = 1;
    d.valorDesconto = 0.05;
    printf("%s\n", itm_showItem(&i1));
}
```

Vale lembrar que essas strings que estão sendo retornadas das funções estão sendo alocadas na heap, é legal dar um free nelas.

Comment: Muito obg pela a explicação, mais tenho uma outra duvida. Se essa duas structs estiverem em arquivos difenrentes como faria pra acessar o Desconto.

Comment: como assim? a definição de cada struct está em um arquivo? No arquivo do Item vc teria que incluir arquivo do desconto com #include

Comment: Isso mesmo. A struct de Desconto está em outro arquivo, assim como Item