# Dúvida sobre ponteiros em C++

Tags: c++, string, ponteiro, char, smart-pointer

Por que se um ponteiro bruto do tipo char estiver apontando para algum caractere de uma `std::string` e imprimir esse ponteiro sem o asterisco (*) ele irá mostrar o resto da string a partir do caractere que ele está apontando, e não o endereço daquele caractere?

Exemplo:

```
int main( void )
{
    std :: string somebody = "Luiz";
    char* pointer = &somebody[ 1 ];
    
    pointer++;

    std :: cout << pointer << std :: endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Saída:

```
iz
```

E por que, quando o mesmo é feito com um ponteiro inteligente (*smart pointer*), há erro?

```
int main( void )
{
    std :: string somebody = "Luiz";
    std :: unique_ptr< char > pointer( &somebody[ 0 ] );
    
    pointer++; //erro ao tentar avançar para o próximo endereço de memória

    std :: cout << pointer << std :: endl; //outro erro por tentar imprimir sem o asterisco (*) ou o e comercial (&)

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Isso acontece porque, quando você faz:

```
std::string somebody = "Luiz";
char* pointer = &somebody[1];
```

Você declara `pointer` como um ponteiro a um caractere.

Você sabe o que é uma string em C? É basicamente um array de caracteres. Em C, o tipo `char*` é comumente usado para apontar ao primeiro caractere dessa lista, que é a string. Veja mais [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/321320/69296).

Como C++ foi criado pensando em certa “compatibilidade” com C, a linguagem dá suporte às chamadas “C strings”. É imprescindível entender que `std::string` e uma C string são coisas diferentes em C++, veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3454900/7445826) para saber mais.

Portanto, o que ocorre é que o operador `<<` irá entender valores do tipo `char*` (tal como o ponteiro que você forneceu no primeiro exemplo) como o primeiro caractere de uma C string. Isso fará com que ele leia até encontrar o NUL *character*.

Veja que o operador `<<` é [sobrecarregado](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_overloading) para lidar com valores do tipo `char*`, e o comportamento definido foi tratá-los como uma string em C e “ler” até encontrar o *NUL char*.

Se você quiser imprimir o endereço de fato, pode fazer um *cast*, assim:

```
std::cout << (void*)pointer << std::endl;
//=> 0x7ffee14b7573
```

E veja que, se você desferenciar o ponteiro, imprimirá somente o caractere apontado (que também é o primeiro caractere da C string):

```
std::cout << *pointer << std::endl;
//=> i
```

---

Sobre os erros em relação ao uso do *smart pointer* `unique_ptr`, antes de tudo você deve se perguntar... Por que está os utilizando?

Não faz muito sentido usar um `unique_ptr` aí. Pelo menos não tendo em vista ao que você virá a fazer logo em seguida.

Ponteiros inteligentes geralmente são utilizados para modificar a semântica de quem é dono do ponteiro fornecido. Você precisa disso?

O erro em relação ao `++` dá-se tendo em vista que valores do tipo `unique_ptr<T>` não definem sobrecarga ao operador `++`. O que isso era para fazer? Incrementar o ponteiro que está dentro do ponteiro inteligente? Ou incrementar o próprio ponteiro inteligente? Este último faz menos sentido, mas seria algo ambíguo.

Veja que agora é mais fácil entender o erro ao tentar usar o `++` em um `unique_ptr`:

> ```
> no operator "++" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::unique_ptr<char, std::default_delete<char>> ++
> ```

O segundo erro, agora em relação ao `<<` também ocorre porque o `<<` não suporta o tipo `unique_ptr<T>` diretamente. Veja a diferença em relação ao `char*` tratado anteriormente, que já é sobrecarregado.

Nesse caso, você deve fazer a desreferência do ponteiro para que possa o utilizar. Ou simplesmente fazer um *cast* e imprimir o endereço, de fato, do ponteiro.

Veja o erro:

> ```
> no operator "<<" matches these operands -- operand types are: std::ostream << std::unique_ptr<char, std::default_delete<char>>
> ```

Assim como a última mensagem, também demonstra que não há sobrecarga para suportar `unique_ptr<T>`.